# Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so on Android 4.4+

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm receiving this error on Android Kitkat 4.4+ devices (mostly Samsung devices):

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/konawifiue/konawifi:4.4.2/KOT49H/N5110UEU2CNE2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '8'
pid: 2692, tid: 2755, name: com.hello.george >>>com.hello.george <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 00000ac3 r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 00000006 r5 00000002 r6 00000ac3 r7 0000010c
r8 6107d880 r9 6107d88c sl 61f1d020 fp 62e33ccc
ip 6107d888 sp 62e33a08 lr 4011410d pc 40123190 cpsr 000f0010
d0 74726f6261204d56 d1 614e2e6d65747379
d2 5374757074754f70 d3 72772e6d61657274
d4 5f4809cccb70b314 d5 000000163ee04578
d6 401e000000000000 d7 4036000000000000
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000000
d18 409f1aa5675c07c8 d19 0000000000000000
d20 4014a978cccccccd d21 4049d3d700000000
d22 bf66bbe9530cccae d23 40c3880000000000
d24 bf95c966ebf3f9b1 d25 3ff0000000000000
d26 4049d3d700000000 d27 bfcc400000000000
d28 bf95c966ebf3f9b0 d29 3fa3afbb7fc903ef
d30 3e6010d43276ab1d d31 4000000000000000
scr 80000011

backtrace:
#00 pc 00022190 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00013109 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
#02 pc 0001331d /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00012053 /system/lib/libc.so
#04 pc 00021a44 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 00046beb /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+78)
#06 pc 000557f5 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDetachCurrentThread()+548)
#07 pc 00049fcb /system/lib/libdvm.so
#08 pc 00006dfc /data/app-lib/com.hello.george-1/libmonodroid.so

code around pc:
40123170 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40123180 ea006ece e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000 
40123190 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
401231a0 ea006ec6 e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000 
401231b0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
401231c0 ea006ebe f200429a bf0080f7 f000f891 
401231d0 4001e92d f040f891 d3532a10 0301ea80 
401231e0 0303f013 806ef000 d3262ae0 0300f1c0 
401231f0 030ff013 eba2d021 ea5f0203 bf447cc3 
40123200 eb01f811 eb01f800 f811bf21 f811cb01 
40123210 f800eb01 f800cb01 ea5feb01 da037c43 
40123220 080df9a1 083df980 f921d303 f900070d 
40123230 f891071d f891f000 3a40f040 f891d30f 
40123240 f891f080 f921f0c0 f921020d f891420d 
40123250 3a40f0c0 020df900 420df900 f102d2f3 
40123260 3a200240 f921d305 3a20020d 020df900 

code around lr:
401140ec 447b4b13 42b3e010 6a1ed10e 44784811 
401140fc ec84f7fb ea7af00d 46224631 e83cf00f 
4011410c d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb 
4011411c 44782403 ec72f7fb f001e002 6804fa8f 
4011412c fa8cf001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003b2b6 
4011413c 0003b2aa 0003b2a2 0003b27e bf7ef7ff 
4011414c 4a3e4b3d e92d447b b08b43f0 4606589c 
4011415c 6823460d 930946a1 fa70f001 8000f8d0 
4011416c d0482d00 f00f4628 280fff25 d8444604 
4011417c ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e944f00d 
4011418c d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debb6 
4011419c e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478 
401141ac 4a2aec2e 46332120 a801447a fa96f013 
401141bc a8012101 fdb0f01a 46061c42 e011d104 
401141cc 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622 
401141dc 1c43e980 d11e4607 fa30f001 29046801
```

This is using Xamarin. I'm not able to interpret this error and haven't found any satisfactory explanations on the net as well. It would be really helpful if somebody could shed some light on the same and point me in the right direction.

Comment: It seems this error message is with a release build. Would you be able to make a debug build and reproduce this crash. The error log would be much more helpful then.

Comment: @Martijn Hi, I'm not able to reproduce it on a Debug build..I will try and let you know.

Comment: I actually had this same crash show up today on a bug report

Comment: @shinjuo did you figure it out?

Comment: @AniketSharma I actually didnt get that error again. Mine happened to be caused by a specific phone type. At least that is what I read online and I never had the issue again. Only that one model of phone

Comment: @shinjuo Actually I think this error is caused by aborting Threads. Once I removed that piece of code I never came across this error.

Comment: @AniketSharma I will check and see if I have a thread abort somewhere, but I have not received that error since it happened the once and it was an obscure phone

Comment: Anyone found the solution? Please help me I'm really stuck on this issue.

Comment: @SagarPanwala Check for thread aborts or other thread related operations in your code.